# Basket file is loaded as numeric. How can I make it load as categorical?

Tags: orange

I am loading a basket file into orange. This is the content of the file:

```
beer, milk
bread, butter
bread, butter, jelly
bread=2, butter
beer, bread
```

If I load this data orange loads the data as categorical as it should. As this is the datatype that allows the usage of [associate rules](http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/reference/rst/Orange.associate.html).

[image: categorical Data]

If however I change milk to bread the data is no longer loaded as categorical.

```
beer, bread
bread, butter
bread, butter, jelly
bread=2, butter
beer, bread
```

[image: numeric Data]

Why is this? How can I can I load the data as categorical? Bear in mind that my real dataset has more than 100 columns.

Comment: Hmmm, `bread=2` of order 2 does not seem categorical. 

Comment: @K3---rnc The file follows the .basket format stated in documentation. I don't know why it is loaded differently when I change the data. What I know however is that when orange detects the data as categorical everything works. If it doesn't it does not work.

Comment: If it looks like a bug, raise an issue on the issue tracker.